# Query about using a thread inside a service. Android

Tags: android, user-interface, service

So I am trying to start a service class from another class. Here is the code...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, abcservice.class);
startService(intent);

stopService(new Intent(xyz.this, abcservice.class));

Intent i= new Intent(xyz.this, ijk.class);
startActivity(i);
```

When the above code runs, my service class runs in the background, while I am taken back to the ujk class(which is totally fine). Inside the onStart(Intent intent, int startId) method in the abcservice class, I am running a thread in the following manner...

```
 @Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.d("S started", "Service is started1");
    Log.d("S started", "Service is started2");
    Log.d("S started", "Service is started3");

    readthread = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            try {
                for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
                    Log.d("S started", "The thread is running ");

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } } });
    readthread.start(); 
}
```

And here is the onDestroy() method..

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("S dest", "Service is destroyed");
}
```

Now in the log i get the following output...

```
Service is started1
Service is started2
Service is started3
Service is destroyed
The thread is running
The thread is running
.....98 more times (Thread is running) ....
```

My queries are...

**1.** Is this the correct output? I mean if the service is destroyed before the thread starts running, how is the thread still running and completing the loop inside it?

**2.** Basically I want to upload a few files to a server and I want to do it in the onStart() method of the service class and using the Thread readthread, is that a good idea? Can I do that? Or is there another simpler and better workaround for achieving this? Or I shouldn't do it in the onStart() method in the service class and somewhere else?

I might be uploading a few video files of a few Mbs. And I want the upload to be ongoing even if I exit the app. I'm a newbie at Android, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to kill the thread in ondestroy() , i think you can do like this :

```
myService.getThread().interrupt();
```

NOTE : the method `Thread.stop()` is deprecated

EDIT : : try this

```
public void stopThread(){
  if(myService.getThread()!=null){
      myService.getThread().interrupt();
      myService.setThread(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would the loop inside the thread run completely (ie 100 times)? Or would it be destroyed as soon as the service is destroyed?

Comment: actually its user thread and its property that it will wait for its child process so just kill that thread in ondestroy() method when ever your work has been done

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest here is a hack, but...

You may declare your service to run in a separate process (see the *process* attribute of the service in the XML). And you may kill that process (see *android.os.Process.killProcess()* and *android.os.Process.myPid()*). This will kill all threads and wipe out all garbage and all memory leaks.

Note that if you use *Thread.interrupt()*, your thread must repeatedly check if it is interrupted. Some java methods throw `InterruptedException` (like *Thread.sleep()* and some i/o methods), but the others do not react on the interrupted status. It is possible that your time-consuming operations will not be interrupted by *Thread.interrupt()*, and the thread will not be interrupted until these time-consuming operations are complete. In addition, some real-life code (probably including the code available for reuse in your project) is written according to what Eclipse suggests: there's an `InterruptedException`, let's surround it with a try/catch that logs the exception and does nothing.